# Can dynatrace monitor API?

Tags: api, monitoring, dynatrace

I am new to the dynatrace and looking for bit help on Dynatrace tool.My query is regarding Dyna-trace capability to monitor APIs.
Is dynatrace capable of monitoring external/3rd party APIs? If yes , where can I find the details?
Thanks!

Comment: You should be more clear in your question. There are two ways to montior an API. One way is to ensure the API is responding (this is called availability). The second way is tracing or measuring the responsiveness of the requests to the API (this is called performance). What kind of monitoring are you looking to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to know which technologies that is being used by your API, then check Dynatrace's release notes:
[Dynatrace AppMon 6.5 release notes](https://community.dynatrace.com/community/pages/viewpage.action?title=Dynatrace%20AppMon%206.5%20Release%20Notes&spaceKey=PROD) : by time, dynatrace releases a new version, so for the version you are looking forward to use, make sure of checking it out.
[Dynatrace SaaS/Managed Supported Technologies](https://help.dynatrace.com/get-started/reference/which-environments-and-versions-does-dynatrace-support/)

If the technologies meets Dynatrace's requirements, then you can check and search their documentation on how to instrument/inject your API and start monitoring it, usually their methods are extremely easy and straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Are the third-party API used by the back-end code or by the front-end/mobile app code? That's quite different.
You can have any kind of details if the backend code is calling them. Usually you should only instrument the method calling them. 
You can monitor the API called by the mobile app but that's a bit more complicated because you need to use the mobile ADK. 
For the API called by the Javascript code in the browser you can have some high-level stats using the plain UEM but you can have more details using the ADK

Answer (score 0):

> Can Dynatrace monitor API?

You need to be specific what parameters or metrics related to APIs you wish to monitor. For practical purposes - Yes, Dynatrace **Appmon** has out-of-the-box dashlet such as API Breakdown that automatically detects the APIs for various .Net and Java based applications.

Please see below snapshot which shows aggregated metric data for various APIs in a sample Java based application.

[API Breakdown Dynatrace Appmon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilZLK.png)

> Is dynatrace capable of monitoring external/3rd party APIs? Where can I find the details?

Since appmon has capability to detect external calls in dashlets such as Web Services, Messaging, Remoting. Also the same can be established by creating custom Business Transactions. You can find more details on [Appmon Documentation](https://www.dynatrace.com/support/doc/appmon/) and Dynatrace AppMon Q&A.

Note: Compuware's Dynatrace is no more an *isolated* APM product. It is has been released as **Dynatrace Appmon** since 2016s.